# One word synonym for "without permission"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What's a one word synonym for "without permission" when pertaining to one of these (or very similar):

- admittance or entrance
- hunting, fishing, swimming
- shirt, shoes, dogs etc
- eating, drinking

Comment: If you have entered without permission you’re *trespassing*. If you’re hunting without permission you’re *poaching*.

Comment: Are you requiring shirts and shoes, or banning them? The former is more common.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: Reopen. This question makes total sense and it's very clear. How is it off-topic?

Answer (score 23):

***unauthorised/unauthorized***

> not having official permission or approval.
>
> - unauthorized access to the computer system ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=unauthorized%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&oq=unauthorized&aqs=chrome.0.0i20i263j69i57j46i433j0l7.12358j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Or

> without someone's official permission to do something or be in a particular place:
>
> - Unauthorized personnel are not admitted beyond this point. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unauthorized))

However, your category of **shirt, shoes, dogs* is a bit strange. I don't see how you could say ***unauthorised shirt, shoes or dogs***... Maybe ***unwanted*** would go better, but this is a different meaning.

It seems to me that ***without permission*** can describe actions, but not persons or objects.

Comment: A far more natural choice. You're right to point out intricacies. I was wondering whether OP wanted an adverb. I wouldn't adverbise our two answers! Perhaps _presumptuously_, though that seems hypernymic. // 'Have you got permission [to ...]?' works, of course.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I would think the OP would have given categories of verbs if he or she were looking for adverbs. We could have definitely used more context, but I seemed to guess a rather formal register of language. In which case, the more common formula would be adj+[verbal/deverbal noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun#:~:text=Deverbal%20nouns%20are%20nouns%20that,of%20nominalization%20(noun%20formation).).

Answer (score 10):

**Unsanctioned** is high register but semantically correct.

> *unsanctioned* [adjective]: lacking effective or authoritative approval or consent: not sanctioned ...
>
> - Historically, swimming in unsanctioned places in the U.S. has proved deadly for people of color. [Anelise Chen, The Atlantic, 27 May 2021]

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsanctioned#:%7E:text=%3A%20lacking%20effective%20or%20authoritative%20approval,sanctioned%20an%20unsanctioned%20boxing%20match%20%E2%80%A6)]

- *[The] unsanctioned use of company cars* [[WordNet](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsanctioned)]

Used predicatively:

- *Any other debates or forums held during that Democratic primary cycle were unsanctioned.* [[reddit blog](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ask_Politics/comments/7d5uwb/what_is_the_difference_between_an_unsanctioned/)]

Comment: An "unsanctioned action" might be [one which wasn't punished](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:52011SC1218&from=EN#:~:text=certain%20abuses%20would%20remain%20unsanctioned), too.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective "*unallowed*" carries the connotation of being unacceptable; it is particularly appropriate in  cases of the the third and fourth type.

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unallowed)) unallowed       in British English, (ˌʌnəˈlaʊd)
> adjective        not allowed or permitted; unacceptable

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sermones_Catholici/DCVLAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22unallowed%22&dq=%22unallowed%22&printsec=frontcover)) Immoderate curiosity is a grave sin; for we should turn our look from evil sight, our hearing from evil speech, our taste from unallowed aliments, our noses from hurtful smells […] Every one of those persons who abstain from unallowed sight , from unallowed hearkening , from unallowed taste , from unallowed smell , from unallowed touch , has the name of maiden for that purity . If it be good and salutary to abstain from ...

Comment: I don't think I've heard "unallowed" used in modern speech (unless it's a regional thing).  It's more common to use "disallowed" instead.

Comment: @Miral It does seem to be restricted in use, I find it used often only with terms in the financial/legal domain ( losses, credit, deductions, expenditure, balance, amount, cost, claim…), technical domain (set, set type, harmonics, band, condition, vertex…), and rare otherwise (column).

Answer (score 2):

**Prohibited**

> : not permitted : forbidden by authority

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prohibited)

Answer (score 1):

I think *forbidden* would work, also *disallowed*.

Comment: This would be improved by including dictionary definitions/links for the two suggested words.

Answer (score 0):

**Verboten**

> not permitted or allowed : forbidden or prohibited by or as if by authority

*These visits … qualify as “research” under the convoluted regulations of the U.S. embargo and are therefore deemed legal, whereas pleasure travel is verboten.*
— Richard Alleman

*Same-sex marriage and gay parents, topics once verboten in mainstream America, have become hot-buttons in this election year.*
— Dirk Johnson et al.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Good word, but worth pointing out that it's a 'loanword' and comes directly from German.  Not everybody would immediately recognise it.